# Network connection exception handling if url not reachable or internet not available

Tags: android

```
try{
  String out_url="http://algotips.com/";
  URL urlObject=new URL(out_url);
  conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
  conn.setReadTimeout(100000);//milliseconds
  conn.setConnectTimeout(150000);//milliseconds
  conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
  conn.setDoInput(true);
}
catch(Exception e){ 
   /*Exception*/ 
}
```

My app is getting crashed with below reasons:

- If internet connection is not available, which means device is not connected to WiFi or WiFi connection is limited.
- If the website is not reachable.

How to handle these scenarios?

Comment: did you write the right permissions on the manifest.xml?
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Which error you get when your app crashes..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checking connectivity availability, before calling the below methods, please use ConnectivityManager to check for connection availability. If not available, show error to usage.

If connection available and URL/Server is not reachable, then the below solution will help you!

For consuming post web-services, this is the code we use:
If the response is null, then may be server issue and we handle it accordingly.

```
private HttpResponse getWebServiceResponse(String URL, ArrayList <NameValuePair> params)
{
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    try 
    {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
        int timeoutConnection = 20000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 20000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);              

        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(appProps.getProperty("USERNAME"), appProps.getProperty("PASSWORD")));    
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
        try 
        {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        }
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return httpResponse;
}
```

For a Get Request, change accordingly (include timeout and socket timeout as in above example):

```
// For calling GET method
public static void callWebServiceGET (String URL, String userName, String password, ArrayList<NameValuePair> params)
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpget;
    String querystring = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
    URL = URL + "?" + querystring;
    log.info("URL to be consumed via GET request is --> " + URL);
    httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null; 
    try 
    {
        httpget.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password),
                "UTF-8", false));

        httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        String respstring = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


        if (entity != null)
        {
            entity.consumeContent();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception caught :: " +e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} // End of method callWebServiceGET
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check the internet before trying to connect to internet..

```
private boolean isConnected(Context ctx){
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) 
                return true;
            else
                return false;   
    }
```